# column mismatch snowflake, Row 1 starts at line 2, column ""table_name""["Account":1]

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

getting this Error on snowflake while uploading the data.
I checked my data frame and also droped index:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

the command i'm executing after saving dataframe in csv:

```
PUT file://test/{file_name}* @~/tm OVERWRITE=TRUE
COPY INTO "Table" from '@~/tm/{file_name}.csv.gz' FILE_FORMAT = 'My_format' ON_ERROR = 'ABORT_STATEMENT' PURGE = TRUE;
```

**Error**

```
ProgrammingError: 100080 (22000): Number of columns in file (1) does not match that of the corresponding table (520), use file format option error_on_column_count_mismatch=false to ignore this error
  File '@~/tm/filename.csv.gzip.gz', line 3, character 1
  Row 1 starts at line 2, column ""filename""["Account":1]
  If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.
```

**uploader Function**:

```
def uploader(d,d_name):
    d.columns = [str(x).replace('\n',"") for x in d.columns]
    for x in d.select_dtypes("object").columns:
        try:
          d[x] = d[x].str.replace("|",";")
          d[x] = d[x].str.replace("\n"," ")
        except:
          print(x)
    
    d.to_csv(f"test/{d_name}.csv",index=False,sep="|")
    
    sql  = pd.io.sql.get_schema(d, d_name,con=cnx).replace("CREATE TABLE","CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE")
    print(cnx.cursor().execute(sql).fetchall())

    cnx.cursor().execute(f"PUT file://test/{d_name}* @~/tm OVERWRITE=TRUE;")
    cnx.cursor().execute(f"""COPY INTO "{d_name}" from '@~/tm/{d_name}.csv.gz' FILE_FORMAT = 'Some_Format' ON_ERROR = 'ABORT_STATEMENT' PURGE = TRUE; """).fetchall()
```

Comment: indexing starts from 0 in python so maybe try changing that 1 to 0

Comment: @Matiiss reset_index does the same thing

Comment: well can You try manually adding that index and testing that way?

Comment: @Matiiss i did and still didnt worked

Comment: well I have no idea about this, just came by and gave a reasonable suggestion (don't have experience with this)

Comment: What is the definition of the file format "My_format"? It looks like the column delimiter might be incorrect as it is interpreting the file as having 1 column instead of the expected 520 columns.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths  "My_format" is "|" separated format with head row =1,and in code i'm replacing all "|" with ";" before saving it "|" sep file.

Comment: Have you inspected the file to make sure it is actually saving with pipe (|) separators? The most likely cause of that issue in my opinion is either the column separators (FIELD_DELIMITER) being mismatched between the file and the format definition, or possibly the line terminator (RECORD_DELIMITER) not matching.

Comment: I'm executing this on a server so not able to check all lines, but i think pandas separated it with |.